# How to access array elements in a Django template?

Tags: django

I am getting an array `arr` passed to my Django template. I want to access individual elements of the array in the array (e.g. `arr[0]`, `arr[1]`) etc. instead of looping through the whole array.

Is there a way to do that in a Django template?

Comment: You can access item like this `arr.0`, `arr.1`, ... Another solution : write your own template tag `arr|array_item: "0" ` or something like this.

Comment: @rphonika Yes, example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29664945/2714931

Comment: @rphonika array_item not found and invalid.

Answer (score 335):

Remember that the dot notation in a Django template is [used for four different notations in Python](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/language/#variables).  In a template, `foo.bar` can mean any of:

```
foo[bar]       # dictionary lookup
foo.bar        # attribute lookup
foo.bar()      # method call
foo[bar]       # list-index lookup
```

It tries them in this order until it finds a match.  So `foo.3` will get you your list index because your object isn't a dict with 3 as a key, doesn't have an attribute named 3, and doesn't have a method named 3.

Comment: Aren't the first and last more like`foo['bar']`?

Comment: There seems to be no way to access a list item using a variable index :(

Comment: Agree with @VickyChijwani: the fourth option above is not valid. Django templates don't seem to do list-index lookups with variables

Comment: @hiyume How to overcome that?

Answer (score 193):

```
arr.0
arr.1
```

etc.

Comment: how to print dynamic like   ex:  arr.variablename

Comment: Is there any way to do this without magic numbers?
In other words to "name" the .0 .1 .2 etc...?
Such as array["first name"], array["last name"] etc..

Comment: @cyberjoac in that case use a dict. In the view: d = {'first_name':'foo', 'last_name': 'bar'}. In the template {{ d.first_name }} will work just fine.

Answer (score 36):

You can access sequence elements with `arr.0`, `arr.1` and so on. See [The Django template system chapter](http://web.archive.org/web/20160902133334/http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter04.html) of the django book for more information.

Answer (score 14):

When you `render` a request to `context` some information, for example:

```
return render(request, 'path to template', {'username' :username, 'email' :email})
```

You can access to it on template, for `variables`

```
{% if username %}{{ username }}{% endif %}
```

for `arrays`

```
{% if username %}{{ username.1 }}{% endif %}
{% if username %}{{ username.2 }}{% endif %}
```

you can also name array objects in `views.py` and then use it as shown below:

```
{% if username %}{{ username.first }}{% endif %}
```