# Reference list item by index within Django template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

This may be simple, but I looked around and couldn't find an answer.  What's the best way to reference a single item in a list from a Django template?

In other words, how do I do the equivalent of `{{ data[0] }}` within the template language?

Answer (score 265, accepted):

It looks like `{{ data.0 }}`. See [Variables and lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups).

Comment: The annoying thing is that I can't say `{{ data.foo }}`, where `foo` is a variable with an index value in it and not a property name.

Comment: If you're willing to create a custom tag, you can do a lot more. Here we're just working with the built-in stuff.

Comment: Link not working anymore, try this one : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups

Answer (score 122):

A better way: custom template filter: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/

such as get my_list[x] in templates:

in template

```
{% load index %}
{{ my_list|index:x }}
```

templatetags/index.py

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def index(indexable, i):
    return indexable[i]
```

if `my_list = [['a','b','c'], ['d','e','f']]`, you can use `{{ my_list|index:x|index:y }}` in template to get `my_list[x][y]`

It works fine with "for"

```
{{ my_list|index:forloop.counter0 }}
```

Tested and works well ^_^

Comment: One of the simplest explanations to learn Template Tags' application!

Comment: This was great!  But with the {{ List|index:x }} format, how do I access values where I would normally use a dot?  {{ (List|index:x).name }} obviously does not work.  Thank you!

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: I have an array in which I'm not sure of the index of my desired value
`{% for id in article_details.heading.contents.article_ids %}
      {% if id.type == 'DOI' %}
        {{ article_details.heading.contents.article_ids.forloop.counter0.value }}
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}`

Comment: I am iterating trough a list(matches), while iterating i have another list where i want to use the index (counter0), i tried {{ matchTeamEmblems.forloop.counter0.homeTeamID }} but it doesnt work, the matchTeamEmblems is a list i generate in simple_tag which builds an URL(static..) for my emblems but i cant access them

Comment: @SuperCode '0' means getting the index which starts from 0, not 1

Comment: Why is this a better way then accesing directly the template loookups for attributes: `data.0` ? In this way you can access it's attributes also: `data.0.some_attribute`.

Comment: this is the better way I think if you need to get the element index (.0, or .1 or .2 etc) from a template variable like forloop.counter :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53287022/django-template-access-to-list-item-by-forloop-counter
it's true this was not the simpler OP question but well its way more interesting

Comment: also, as @JTFouquier asked, you can access element attributes using **with** as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53287022/django-template-access-to-list-item-by-forloop-counter)

Answer (score 26):

`{{ data.0 }}` should work.

Let's say you wrote `data.obj` django tries `data.obj` and `data.obj()`. If they don't work it tries `data["obj"]`. In your case `data[0]` can be written as `{{ data.0 }}`. But I recommend you to pull `data[0]` in the view and send it as separate variable.

Answer (score 2):

@jennifer06262016, you can definitely add another filter to return the objects inside a django Queryset.

```
@register.filter 
def get_item(Queryset):
    return Queryset.your_item_key
```

In that case, you would type something like this {{ Queryset|index:x|get_item }} into your template to access some dictionary object. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

first make sure that the app contain custom tag function is added to **INSTALLED APP** follow the instruction below

**1** in the main directory app create another directory with name **templatetags** at the same level as model.py,views.py,urls.py.

**2** inside of templatetags directory create **init**.py and another file with the name of your custom tags, for example: my_tags.py.

```
MainApp/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    templatetags/
        __init__.py
        my_tags.py
    views.py
```

in your template you would use the following:

```
{% load my_tags.py %}
```

in my_tags.py:

```
from django import template 
register = template.Library()
@register.filter(name="get")
def get(indexable, i):
    return indexable[i]
```

in views.py:

```
number = [0,1,2,3,4,5]

return render(
    "index.html", {"number":number}
```

)

in index.html:

```
{% load my_tags %}

{{numer|get:forloop.counter0}}
```

reference [How to create custom template tags and filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/)

*i hope you understand, because ingles not my native language*