# Reference list items by index Django template

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a list called **forms** which I am passing to a Django (1.5.1) template:

```
<div class="content">
{% if forms %}
  <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="survey">
   <div class="image">
     {{ forms.0.as_p }}
    </div>
    <div class="questions">
    {% for form in forms %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Survey"/>
  </form>
{% endif %}
<div class="content">
```

I want to do two separate things:

1. Put the first element of the **forms** list inside a div tag with class="image".
2. Put the rest of the elements inside a div tag with class="questions"

There are [SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651172/reference-list-item-by-index-within-django-template) about how to reference list items by index inside a django template, but `forms.0.as_p` doesn't render anything for me. Also, how to get a sublist of items from **forms** (something like forms[1:])?

**EDIT**

While the question has been correctly answered below, I'll add another way of doing it using slice.

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="survey">
 <div class="image">
  {{ forms.0.as_p }}
 </div>
 <div class="questions">
  {% with myforms=forms|slice:"1:"%}
   {% for form in myforms %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
   {% endfor %}
  {% endwith %}
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`forloop.first`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#for) variable to determine the first form in the list:

```
{% for form in forms %}
<div class="{{ forloop.first|yesno:'image,question' }}">
   {{ form.as_p }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

P.S. You don't need it for this case but to get the sublist in the template you can use the [`slice`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#slice) template filter.

Comment: It is creating an empty div element called image. All elements of the "forms" list is appearing with the div element "question"

Comment: @rivu You must have an empty form at index 0. How do you construct forms list?

Comment: This means that the first element of the `forms` list is empty.  And I suspect this is why it doesn't render anything with the `{{ forms.0.as_p }}` tag.  How do you create it?

Comment: yes you are right, the first element f the list is empty. I was improvising on django-crowdsourcing for my purpose. I'll check again. thanks.