# Django: How to iterate over two lists inside template

Tags: python, django

From views.py I send to template 2 array:

1. animal: `['cat','dog','mause']`
2. how_many: `['one','two','three']`

Template:

```
{% for value in animal %}
    animal:{{ value }}  \ how meny  {{ how_many[(forloop.counter0)]  }}
{% endfor %}
```

In the for loop I want to read an iteration and then use it in a second array, but I can't get it to work. I'm a beginner.

Comment: Don't do that, send `zip(animal, how_many)` from views.py.

Answer (score 8):

According to the docs, [*you can't do that straightforward*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups):

> Note that “bar” in a template expression like {{ foo.bar }} will be interpreted as a literal string and not using the value of the variable “bar”, if one exists in the template context.

I would suggest you to add `zip(animal, how_many)` to your template's context:

```
context['animals_data'] = zip(animal, how_many)
```

Then you can access both lists:

```
{% for animal, how_many in animals_data %}
    {{ animal }} {{ how_many }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: getting this error "context must be a dict rather than zip."

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
animal = ['cat','dog','mause']
how_many = ['one','two','three']
data = zip(animal,how_many)
return render_to_response('your template', {'data': data})
```

In Template

```
{% for i,j in data %}
{{i}}   {{j}}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend writing your own template tag for this problem. Put the following (from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29664945/3672986)) in a template called index which should be saved in `templatetags/index.py`:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def index(List, i):
    return List[int(i)]
```

Now, loading this and using it should be as simple as:

```
{% load index %}
{% for value in animal %}
  animal:{{ value }}  \ how meny {{ how_meny|index:forloop.counter0 }}
{% endfor %}
```