# access first message in Django template

Tags: python, django

I am using the following code to access the first message in Django template,

```
{% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
        {%  if forloop.first  %}
                {{ message }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

How I can achieve the same without using the for loop in a single statement.

Comment: See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651172/reference-list-item-by-index-within-django-template)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following should work:

```
{% if messages %}
    {{ messages.0 }}
{% endif %}
```