# How can i access this JSON data in Django?

Tags: python, json, django

**Code i used in fetching the data**

```
url = 'https://api.some-random-url.com/users/amarlearning'
serialized_data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read().decode("utf-8")
data = json.loads(serialized_data)
```

**Returned JSON**

```
[
   {
       id: "4859421681",
       type: "IssueCommentEvent"
   },
   {
       id: "4859421681",
       type: "IssueCommentEvent"
   },
   {
       id: "4859421681",
       type: "IssueCommentEvent"
   }
]
```

**Now In django Template i am doing this**

```
{{ data[0]['type'] }}
```

Getting Template error, while i was accessing Json data in Django template!

Comment: This is not how keys and indexes are accessed in django templates. You  can get it by data.0.type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/templates/#variables) says -

> Dictionary lookup, attribute lookup and list-index lookups are implemented with a dot notation

So you can access the data via -

```
data.0.type
```

Answer (score 1):

Syntax in Django templates are different from the plain python. You have to do:

```
data.0.type
```

For details also check:

- [Reference list item by index within Django template?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4651208/2063361)
- [how to access dictionary element in django template?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1275999/2063361)

---

In case you want to print all the items within the `JSON`, loop in your template file should be like:

```
{% for d in data %}
    {% for key in d %}
        {{d.key}}
    {% endfor %} 
{% endfor %}
```