# How to use variable in list of lists django template

Tags: django, django-templates

code in views.py. `f` is a list of lists.

```
f = [((1,2,3), (4,5,6)), ((1,2,3), (4,5,6))]

return render(request, 'site/blabla.html', {'f': f, 'n': 1})
```

code in blabla.html

```
{% for pr in f %}
#return empty    
<td>{{ pr.n }}</td>
#return value from the list
<td>{{ pr.1 }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

How to make Django accept `n` as parameter? Or maybe there is another way to accomplish this?

Comment: What is pr? pr.n and pr.1 seem weird to me.

Comment: f is list of lists, so pr == f. I'll add more description to my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use custom-template-tags.
For example here an answer:

[get elemet by index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651172/reference-list-item-by-index-within-django-template/29664945#29664945)

Comment: Thank you sir. I'll try it. It looks promising