# Django template get element in list of dictionary by index

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have the following:

```
item0 = [{'itemCode': 'AZ001', 'price': 15.52}, {'itemCode': 'AB01', 'price': 31.2}, {'itemCode': 'AP01', 'price': 1.2}]
item1 = [{'itemCode': 'BZ001', 'price': 12.55}, {'itemCode': 'BB01', 'price': 34.1}]
```

In django template I would like to display the price of the elements of each list by index: 15.52, 12.55 then 31.2, 34.1 then 1.2

List sizes might not be equal, so I am sending the size of the largest list.

Iterating over the max list size:

`{{i.item|index:forloop.counter0}}` gets me `{'itemCode': 'AZ001', 'price': 15.52}`

If I want price, what can I do?

Doing `{{i.item|index:forloop.counter0.price}}` is giving me invalid key price at index 0.

In other words, I am sending elements in column order and would like to display them in row order without doing list comprehension using zip on the server.

Any solution?

Comment: You probably need to give more context. Normally instead of using a template tag to get an index based on forloop.counter0, you would iterate directly through item: `{% for elem in i.item %}... {{ elem.price }}`. Why can't you do that?

Comment: I have multiple lists that I am comparing next to each other. so I need to display them in row based, when I am sending them column based. I can do zip on the server, but I am trying other ways before going to zip.

Comment: Also if you trying to access first element of list then you can do:
`item.0.price`.

Comment: You could write a [custom template tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29664945/113962). However using `zip` (or `zip_longest` for lists with different lengths) seems like a better approach to me.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I get your question right, but this is the code what you are asking for.

`views.py`:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['item'] = [{'itemCode': 'AZ001', 'price': 15.52}, {'itemCode': 'AB01', 'price': 31.2}]
        return context
```

`template.html`:

```
{{ item.0.price }}
```

Results in 15.52

---

If you want to loop over it you can do it like so:

```
{% for i in item %}
    {{ i.price }}
{% endfor %}
```

---

After you have updated the question, I would do the following:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    item0 = [{'itemCode': 'AZ001', 'price': 15.52}, {'itemCode': 'AB01', 'price': 31.2}, {'itemCode': 'AP01', 'price': 1.2}]
    item1 = [{'itemCode': 'BZ001', 'price': 12.55}, {'itemCode': 'BB01', 'price': 34.1}]
    import itertools
    context['zip_longest'] = itertools.zip_longest(item0, item1)
    return context
```

`template.html`:

```
{% for element in zip_longest %}
    {% for item in element %}
        {% if item %}
            {{ item.price }} <br>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Results in:

```
15.52 
12.55 
31.2 
34.1 
1.2
```

In my opinion, it's nothing wrong with using [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest), since it yields the values from a generator.

Comment: Edited the questions to explain more

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
     {% for key, value in dictionary.items %}
     <li><a href="{{key}}">{{value}}</a></li>
     {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

try using this, [reference](https://www.gun.io/blog/how-to-list-items-in-a-dictionary-in-a-django-template)