# django template access to list item by forloop.counter

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to loop over my model's query set in the Django template. I can do it simply using Django `for loop` but I can not do it for steps more than 1,Here is my code

```
 {% for map in maps %}

 {% if  forloop.counter|divisibleby:2 %}

   #Here I can access Maps with index of 1,3,5 and ..
   #How can I access map with index 2,4,6 here at the same time sth like Map[forloop.counter+1]

 {% endif %}


 {% endfor %}
```

In fact I want a way to acces `Map[forloop.counter+1]` in my template but I have no idea how to do that

Comment: use `{% else %}`  ?

Comment: No I can not use else, as I want step my for +2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a custom template filter as defined here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#registering-custom-filters

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()
@register.filter
def list_item(lst, i):
    try:
        return lst[i]
    except:
        return None
```

Inside your template, use it like:

```
{% for map in maps %}

 {% if  forloop.counter|divisibleby:2 %}

 {% with maps|list_item:forloop.counter+1 as another_map %}

 {{another_map.id}}

 {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

**Where to write template tags?**
Create a directory `templatetags` at the same level as `models.py`, `views.py`. Then add `__init__.py` and a file `maps_tags.py`. Write the custom tag definition in `maps_tags.py`. In your template, load the template tags by writing `{% load maps_tags %}` at the top. More documentation at  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout

Comment: Hi, thanks very much, How can I manage to get info from map?for example `{{ maps|list_item:forloop.counter+1 }}.id` is it possible?

Comment: @MajidHojati You'll have to use `with`. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can combine more than one forloop and implement your custom logic for this, but not access in the same time. Below all forloops from Django 2.1 documentation.

```
forloop.counter     The current iteration of the loop (1-indexed)
forloop.counter0    The current iteration of the loop (0-indexed)
forloop.revcounter  The number of iterations from the end of the loop (1-indexed)
forloop.revcounter0     The number of iterations from the end of the loop (0-indexed)
forloop.first   True if this is the first time through the loop
forloop.last    True if this is the last time through the loop
forloop.parentloop  For nested loops, this is the loop surrounding the current one
```

tell me, What is the problem that you want solve? Maybe you can create a custom tamplate tag or template filter.

Comment: But How can I acces `maps[forloop.counter ]`? my problem is accessing the maps by `forloop.counter` index

Answer (score 2):

In Django you can use `{{ forloop.counter }}` index starts at 1 or `{{ forloop.counter0 }}` index starts at 0.

Maybe you can use this to acces the index+1

I hope this helped. You can read more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for)

Comment: But How can I acces `maps[forloop.counter ]`?