# django template get a list item using a template variable as index

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Supposing a `list0` with elements `['a','b','c','d']`, I need to get the nth element depending on a template variable like [`forloop.counter0`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for) or any other integer available from the template.

So far the better way I found was to create a custom tag as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53287498/1916562) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29664945/1916562) and in the [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters).
Once defined you can write something like :

```
{% for elm in list0 %}
{{ elm }} {{ list1|index:forloop.counter0 }}
{% endfor %}
```

The example assumes there's another list `list1`, with elements `['A','B','C','D']`.
`index` is the name of the custom filter, it uses the forloop counter as an index to get each `list1` element : `list1[0]`, `list1[1]`, `list1[2]`, `list1[3]`

So this generates :

```
a A
b B
c C
d D
```

**But what if you only want to use builtin filters ?**
(Or have spare time for recreative stuff ?)
After some research and tests the only way I found is this odd thing :

```
{% for elm in list0 %}

{% with sl0=forloop.counter0|make_list sl1=forloop.counter|make_list %}
{% with header_id=sl0.0|add:":"|add:sl1.0 %}

{{ elm }} {{ list1|slice:header_id|join:"" }}

{% endwith %}
{% endwith %}

{% endfor %}
```

what it does :

> It uses the [slice](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slice) builtin filter. slice needs a string representing a python list part like `'[2:3]'` which is generated by the second `with` and the two `add`. So one need to slice one member at a time using the forloop counters : `'[0:1]'`, `'[1:2]'`, `'[2:3]'`...But `forloop.counter0` and `forloop.counter` are integers, and `add` does not generate a string in this case. It tries to get an integer as a result. So it needs to be converted to a string. This is why `make_list` is used in the first `with`, as it's the only way I found so far to change an integer into a string..finally slice returns a list with one element so it uses a `join:""` to convert it to a string.

I hope I missed something in the documentation because the code above is.. well.. terrible - but funny.

How could I address this need in an efficient way using django template builtins ?
I agree it should be adressed when building the context in the view and not in the template, but let's say it cannot be done.

Comment: In the view `zip_obj = zip(list0, list1)`, in the template `{% for elm0, elm1 in zip_obj %}`, why do all this indexing and what not in the template? Also you didn't miss anything in the documentation as it is a deliberate design decision to separate the template from the logic.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat: yes, that is exacly to prevent what happens here, that people write complex code, that will typically require a lot of cycles.

Comment: thanks. in my question, please note "I agree it should be adressed when building the context in the view and not in the template, but let's say it cannot be done.". obviously I know about zip(). Also since there's a slice template filter, why not an index one ?

Answer (score 0):

You should not do this in a template, a template is for *rendering* logic, it i up to the view to provide the correct structure. We can do this with [**`zip(…)`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def my_view(request):
    list0 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    list1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
    list01 = zip(list0, list1)
    return render(request, 'some_template.html', {'list01': list01})
```

and then render this with:

```
{% for elm0, elm1 in list01 %}

{{ elm0 }} {{ elm1 }}

{% endfor %}
```