# Is there a way to render a formset in Django without for loop?

Tags: python, django

I'd like to know if there's a way to reference the individual forms of a formset in Django without using a for loop.

This is what all the docs search results point to:

```
    {% for form in formset %}
        {{ form }}
    {% endfor %}
```

I'd like to know if there's anyway to do this:

```
    {{ form[0] }}
    {{ form[1] }}
    {{ form[2] }}
```

I can't find anything that does it and beginning to think it's not possible.

Comment: The question is unclear, in the first block you are rendering the full form, in the second block you are trying to render a form field. If `formset` supports indexing, then `formset.0` shall give you the first form. And then you can try to access a particular field using `formset.0.field`

Comment: Thanks @awesoon. Despite my error, you've managed to answer my question. I'll edit inline with what I had intended.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference list item by index within Django template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651172/reference-list-item-by-index-within-django-template)

Comment: If the issue is only with `form[0]` vs `form.0`, then the linked question contains some related info.