# Is it necessary to loop over a queryset passed to a django template when there is only one record?

Tags: django, django-templates

When I want to show a queryset passed to a template in Django, and there is only one record, is it necessary to loop?

I have something like:

```
{% for x in blobs%}
    {{ x.id }}
{% endfor %}
```

Which works fine. But only one record is in blobs, as it was filtered to a specific id by the view.

Would it not be better than to just access {{blobs.id}} directly? If so, what is the correct way to do that?

Comment: Hey, it'd be better if you also add the queryset you're using.

Comment: @prakasht I didn't think that was relevant. It has an id field which displays when looping over it, I just want to access it outside of the loop.

Comment: Can you use objects.get() instead of objects.filter(), i.e., only send the object to template? You can also try index based lookup, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651172/reference-list-item-by-index-within-django-template

Comment: if you sure that there would be only one result, you can add `blob.first()` to your template context instead of adding blob/ and then you can use `blob.id` in template. but if you sure that you always have only 1 result in your queryset, that don't use `Model.objects.filter(id=...)`, use `Model.objects.get(pk=...)`

Comment: @AndreyMaslov thank you for explaining, that is good advice, I will implement now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you blobs is a list, you cant access like that. your blobs is list with one element. something like
`[blob,]` this. In a python script you can access that like `blobs[0].id` and to achieve that in template you can do `{{blobs.0.id}}`

Comment: For sure I just had to wait to do so. Thanks again.