# display number of views for each post for a specific author

Tags: django

i want to print number of views for a specific post for e.g barack obama = 3 albert einstein = 1 elon musk = 0 that's it,
but it print multiple values for each entries as you can see in the image.
so how to achieve this. should i have to use dictionary or what ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3Yxi.png)

```
models.py
class ObjectViewed(models.Model):
    user            =       models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ip_address      =       models.CharField(max_length=220, blank=True, null=True)
    content_type    =       models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE) # User, Blog, or any other models
    object_id       =       models.PositiveIntegerField() # User id, Blog id, or any other models id
    content_object  =       GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    timestamp       =       models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

views.py
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'edmin/post/postList.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering_by = ['-created']

    def get_queryset(self):
        post=Post.objects.filter(author=self.request.user)
        return post

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        post=Post.objects.filter(author=self.request.user)
        c_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Post)
        context['count_view'] = [ObjectViewed.objects.filter(content_type=c_type, object_id=p.id) for p in post ]
        print(context['count_view'])
        return context

postList.html
<table id="table_id" class="table display" border='2' align="center">
    <thead>
        <tr>
           <th scope="col">#</th>
           <th scope="col">Title</th>
           <th scope="col">Banner Title</th>
           <th scope="col">Created</th>
           <th scope="col">Number of Views</th>
           <th scope="col">Status</th>
           <th scope="col">Edit</th>
           <th scope="col">Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody style="color:#000">
        {% for post in posts %}
              {% if post.status == 'Draft' %}
                    
              {% else %}
                   <tr>
                       <th scope="row">{{ forloop.counter }}</th>
                       <td><a style="color:blue" href="{% url 'edmin:post_detail_view' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></td>
                       <td>{{ post.banner_title }}</td>
                       <td>{{ post.created }}</td>
                       <td>
                          {% for c in count_view %}
                          {{ c|length }}
                          {% endfor %}
                        </td>
                        <td>{{ post.status }}</td>
                        <td><a href="{% url 'edmin:post_update_view' pk=post.pk %}" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm">Edit</a></td>
                        <td><a href="" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm">Delete</a></td>
                  </tr>
                {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem of your code:

```html
<td>
  {% for c in count_view %}
    {{ c|length }}
  {% endfor %}
</td>
```

I believe `count_view` is the list of all the view count across objects? If that's the case, the event in your screen will happen because you displayed all items in the `count_view` list. You might need to change this part to:

```html
<td>
  {{ count_view.forloop.counter }}
</td>
```

You need to get the view for a specific post, not to print out every single one of them. You might need to check as I don't know where your list starts, but this is briefly how this works.

[Research](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4651208/12467282)