# How to get the first element of an array Python, from HTML

Tags: python, html, django, arrays, printing

I have an array called list, for example

`list = [0,1,2,3]`

in the HTML when i do this

```
<body>
{{ list }}
</body>
```

the output will be `[0,1,2]`

what i want is

```
{{ list[0] }}
```

but this statement is giving me error, how i can just print the first element

Comment: `{{ list[0] }}` is neither HTML nor Python.  What else are you using?

Comment: This is Django. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700661/access-array-elements-in-a-django-template

Comment: @msytNadeem **[0,1,2]** isn't an array, it's a list; **array('l', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])** IS an array. _In Rome , do as the Romans do._

Comment: @eyquem A list is nothing but a sophisticated array I thought! But why that doesn't work? Is that a issue with templates?

Comment: @tamizhgeek I don't speak of an array in the vague sense of everyday usage, I speak of Python's types and of this one in particular: (http://docs.python.org/library/array.html#module-array) A Python's array can't be sophisticated to represent a list because _"Arrays are sequence types and behave very much like lists, except that the type of objects stored in them is constrained."_

Comment: @eyquem Thanks! I learned a new thing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using Django, try this: `{{ list.0 }}` or for slicing: `{{ list|slice:":1" }}`

Docs: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#slice