# Django string index out of range

Tags: python, django, templates

Very confused. I have a variable that has 32 items in it, and I'm trying to do a for loop but it's saying "Caught IndexError while rendering: string index out of range"

Any ideas? The variable definitely isn't empty.

```
{% if photos %}
    <ul class="photo-grid">
        {% for photo in photos %}
                <li>
                        <img src="{{ photo.images.low_resolution.url }}" />
                </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    No photos found.
{% endif %}
```

Comment: the error might be getting triggered from somewhere else. Looking to code that resolves for `photo.images.low_resolution.url`?

Comment: are u sure its not from your views.py that your error arises? From what i know, by default variable error in the templates will fail silently

Comment: traceback - something is taking an index of something, somewhere :D. Edit: Wow, the power of the Python tag.

Comment: Looks actually like one of your `photo` dict/object doesn't have the keys you are trying to access. My guess is that either `photo.images` or `photo.images.low_resolution` or `photo.images.low_resolution.url` is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem might be with the `photo.images` part of the value.  Is `images` an array or collection in the photo object?  If it is an array, the `images.low_resolution` is  trying to access the image in the array at the index value of `low_resolution` which is probably not what you want (or maybe it is???).  You might need to add some logic to loop over the `photo.images` rather than trying to access it the way you are now.

See this answer for other info:  [How to access array elements in a Django template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700661/access-array-elements-in-a-django-template)