# How can I use a variable to lookup in a tuple? (Django)

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a tuple, such that

```
{{VISIBILITY_CHOICES.1.1}}
```

Outputs "hello".

I have model "task" with a attribute "visibility_status", and in a loop, say all the iterations of task.visibility_status outputs 1

```
{{task.visibility_status}}
```

Outputs 1.

How do I use this task.visibility_status inside the lookup of the tuple? Something like VISIBILITY_CHOICES[task.visibility_status][1] in a different language.

I'm very new to django... Thanks a lot.

edit:
The code I was running:

```
{% for task in tasks %}
    <div class="post">
         <h1><a href="">{{ task.subject }}</a></h1>
         <div class="date">
             <p>Due: {{ task.due_date }}</p>
             <p>Assigned to: {{task.assigned_to}}</p>
         </div>
         <p>{{ task.text_area|linebreaks }}</p>
         {% with args=""|add:task.visibility_status|add:",1" %}
         <p>Visibility Status: {{VISIBILITY_CHOICES|get_index:args}}({{ task.visibility_status }})</p>
         {% endwith %}
         <p>Case Status: {{ task.case_status }}</p>
         <div class="date">
             <p>Created: {{ task.created_date }} by {{ task.author }}</p>
         </div>
     </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Write a custom template filter. See: [How can I use a variable as index in django template?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376576/how-can-i-use-a-variable-as-index-in-django-template)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the builtin name `tuple` may not have any syntactic meaning in a template, I'll use `my_tuple` in its place in the code below.

I've used `with` to create a context that builds the args for indexing `my_tuple` (i.e `task.visibility_status` and `1`): :

```
{% with x=task.visibility_status|stringformat:"s" %}
{% with args=x|add:",1" %}

    {{ my_tuple|get_index:args }}

{% endwith %}
{% endwith %}
```

And in the [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters), I've splitted and recreated the arguments and used indexing in plain python to return the item at the index:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def get_index(my_tuple, args):
    arg1, arg2 = args.split(',') # split on the comma separator
    try:
        i = int(arg1)
        j = int(arg2)
        return my_tuple[i][j] # same as my_tuple[task.status][1]
    except: 
        return None
```

Comment: add:task.status has problem; the variable is not passed into the template filter.
When I output "args", it just shows ",1"
{{task.status}} still outputs correctly in the template.

Comment: What I want is 
    {% with args=""|add:{{task.status}}|add:",1" %}
but this is invalid code, of course.

Comment: what does `{{task.status}}` show? You wouldn't need to use `{{}}` inside a `{%%}`

Comment: It shows integer 1, 2, or 3, depending on which instance of the loop it's in.

Comment: Are you running the loop outside `with` or inside? May you could update your post with that part of your template.

Comment: I posted the actual code I was using along with the proper names of the tuple,  model attributes, etc... thanks a lot.

Comment: It worked! I'm not sure why, maybe django template language is not as smart as I hoped. Thanks a lot!