# How to access a given list element in django templates?

Tags: python, css, django

I have a list of values in my view where I want to store some classes name and pass them to the template. Here is the list in the view: `menu = ['','disabled','','','']` and my code for the template `<li class="{{ menu|slice:"1:2"|first }}"></li>`.

So far this is the only working code I came with, is there a better way to retrieve the element `menu[2]` from this list? what is the proper way in django to callback the `element[n]` of a list within the template?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access array elements in a Django template?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700661/how-to-access-array-elements-in-a-django-template)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`menu.1` should work

if you know the exact index of your list, it could be cleaner and more explicit to do retrieval in your view.

`context['menu_target'] = menu[1]`

instead of having a list of empty values and accessing them in your template

Comment: `menu.1` works very well, thx. I have 5 menu entries where I want to shift between the css classes `active`, `disabled` and `''` (depending on the view). How would you do?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `menu.2` in your template.

Comment: TS asks: *"is there a better way to retrieve the element menu[2] from this list?"*

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to get the `element[n]` that you need in your view, and pass it to the template directly.

Generally speaking, It's a better approch to pass to the template the data that you're going to actually use. So why pass a full list to use only one item of it?