# How to iterate the values in the list in django template?

Tags: django, templates, filter

I am going to print four array values simultaneously in django template . like this 
the four arrays are of equal length ,they are header_list , domain_list , domain_data , dom

```
for i in range(10):
      print headerlist[i]
      print domain_list[i]
      print domain_data[i]
      print dom[i]
```

how to acheive these in django template .

also tried

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()
@register.filter(name='myrange')
def myrange(number):
    return range(number)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access array elements in a Django template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700661/how-to-access-array-elements-in-a-django-template)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should zip these items in the view, rather than sending them separately to the template.

```
data = zip(header_list , domain_list , domain_data , dom)
return render(request, 'my_template.html', {'data': data, ...})
```

Now you can do:

```
{% for item in data %}
    Header: {{ item.0 }}
    Domain: {{ item.1 }}
    Domain data: {{ item.2 }}
    Dom: {{ item.3 }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It worked . Also i need to know how to access a list of list . 
bcoz domain_data is a list of list . so i need to access it .

Comment: You can just iterate over it: `{% for dd in item.2 %}`

Comment: how to use forloop.counter0 here?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done this way:

**views.py**

```
n = len(headerlist)
context['n'] = range(n)
```

Now in template

```
{% for i in n %}
   {{headerlist.i}}
   {{domain_list.i}}
   {{domain_data.i}}
   {{dom.i}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: template  
`

{% for i in length %}
{{header_list.i}}
{{domain_data.i}}

  {% endfor %}

`
Views.py 
`context = {
                'header_list' : (header_list),
                'domain_list' : abt_link ,

                'domain_data' : dom_data ,


                'domain_data' : dom_data,
                'length' : range(n) ,}
`

Comment: don't use length use **n**

Comment: but both are same , isn't it ?

Comment: no, length is predefined in Django template, so it may override

Comment: still it prints nothing

Comment: **views.py**
`context = {
                'header_list' : (header_list),
                'domain_list' : abt_link ,

                'domain_data' : dom_data ,


                'domain_data' : dom_data,
                'n' : range(n) ,}
`

Comment: try printing n and header_list, in template and see if data is there in it and let me know.

Comment: yeah , n and header_list are printing . when i used {{n}} {{header_list}}

Comment: @DanielRoseman, Can you suggest another answer or edit this one, it will be a great help.