# Display values ​from a dictionary in python

Tags: python, django

I converted the python dictionary into a python object, but I can't display the values ​​of the sub-array D

Views.py

```
def dictToObject(request):
  dictionnaire={'A': 1, 'B': {'C': 2},'D': ['E', {'F': 3}],'G':4}
  obj=json.loads(json.dumps(dictionnaire))
  context={'obj':obj}
  return render(request,'cart/cart_detail.html',context)
```

cart_detail.html

```
  {{ obj.D[0] }}
  {{ obj.D[1].F }}
```

I get an error (**Could not parse the remainder: '[0]' from 'obj.D[0]'**), I don't know why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing dictionary by key in Django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19745091/accessing-dictionary-by-key-in-django-template) also [How to access array elements in a Django template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700661/how-to-access-array-elements-in-a-django-template)

Comment: `{{ obj.D.0 }}` and `{{ obj.D.1.F }}`

Comment: it still doesn't show up, even if I put them in a for loop

Answer (score -1):

Inside a `{% %}` tag, variables aren't surrounded by `{{.`

Comment: Is this answer meant for this question or did you post on the wrong one?

Comment: Can you explain with more detail.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps

```
{{ obj.D.0 }}
{{ obj.D.1.F }}
```

as @AbdulAzizBarkat mentioned in the comment.